# How to post MySql row variable using Javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a html table populated with mysql data. Each row has an id (e.g 001, 002 etc). Within each table row I have created a button. I'd like to be able to post the current time in milliseconds (working fine) as well as the relevant id of the row (which the button clicked is in) to an Ajax file. My Ajax file works fine I just can't get the right id to post.

I have tried using `<?php echo $row=$REQUEST ['id']?>` but it only returns the first value in the table not the respective one.

```
<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th><strong>ID Number</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Class</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Crew</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Start</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Finish</strong></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
   <tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row["number"];?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row["class"];?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row["crew"]?></td>
      <td> <input type="hidden" id="boatnumber" name="custId" value="<?php echo $row["number"];?>"<button id="startbutton" type="submit" class="newbutton"></td></tr>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var delay = 2000;
   $('.newbutton').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var d = new Date();
     var start = d.getTime()
     var id = $('#id').val();
     if(start == ''){
        $('.message_box').html(
            '<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Username!</span>');
        $('#start').focus();
        return false;
     }

     var boatnumber = $('#boatnumber').val();
     if(boatnumber == ''){
        $('.message_box').html('<span style="color:red;">Enter Your Boat 
        ID!`</span>');
        $('#boatnumber').focus();
        return false;
     }

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/start.php",
        data: "start="+start+"&boatnumber="+boatnumber,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.message_box').html(
            '<img src="Loader.gif" width="25" height="25"/>');},         
                success: function(data){
                   setTimeout(function() {
                      $('.message_box').html(data);}, delay);
                   }
                });
         });            
});
</script>
```

It only sends the id of the first row in the table not the id of the row where the button (that is clicked) is.

Comment: I'd hugely appreciate any help!

Comment: Is this code complete? Cant see any form tags.

Comment: Is the boatnumber the ID (001, 002 and so forth)?
Also Your code does not show an ID in tr tag

Comment: You lost underscore in your request superglobal variable, it should be $_REQUEST

Comment: Yes the boat number is 001 002 so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the value of an element with the ID of `#boatnumber`, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID.

A better way maybe to use a data attribute on the button that holds the `number` and then retreive it in your script.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="newbutton" data-number="<?php echo $row['number'] ?>">
```

Script:

```
var boatnumber = $(this).data('number);
```